# Rank of a large matrix

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose i want to calculate rank of a large $N\times N$ matrix having only $0$ and $1$ which is represented by $M$ segments each segment here is depicting that for a segment [LEFT,RIGHT] the row of matrix has all its elements $1$ in range from LEFT to RIGHT.

Now suppose the matrix is too large Let say $N$ is of $10^5$ range , which means i can't find its rank by simply converting it into a matrix and applying some known methods to find it like say Gaussian elimination.

Now I need to find its rank by storing these pairs only.

So Question is how to find the rank in efficient manner both regarding space as well as time.

Like if we have $N=6$ and we have $5$ segments that are : $[1,3] , [2,5] , [1,2] , [4,6]$ and $[3,6]$ the matrix will be 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 1& 1& 1& 0\\
1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1\\
0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Check out the term structural rank. That at least gives you an upper bound on the rank.

Comment: @rajb245 I need to find exact rank, not an upperbound

Comment: Is this ultimately going to be a computation you solve with a computer code? Or you want an algorithm description as an answer?

Comment: @rajb245 I want a algorithm description as answer and yeah i am going to compute it by computer